# how do I pass info to my main class from a child class

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I have two classes, the main from WPF and a child class called 'PersistDataToTable' inside 'PersistDataToTable.Persist' I have a loop and I want to pass that loop incrament back to the main WPF class to show in the progress bar.
I have a backgroundworker thread running the method that hits the loop, I just don't know how to get the data back to the ReportProgress method from the backgroundworker thread.

```
private void PersistDataToDb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                PersistDataToTable persistData = new PersistDataToTable();
                persistData.Persist(seriesId);

                worker.ReportProgress(loop incrament from persist()??);

            };

        worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object o, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
            { 
                int percentage = args.ProgressPercentage;
                progressBar.Value = percentage;
            };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the `worker.ReportProgress` as an `Action<Int>` into your `Persist` method so it updates back to your UI

Example:

```
private void PersistDataToDb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    worker.DoWork += delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            PersistDataToTable persistData = new PersistDataToTable();
            persistData.Persist(seriesId, worker.ReportProgress);
        };

    worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object o, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            int percentage = args.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBar.Value = percentage;
        };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public class PersistDataToTable
{
    public void Persist(int seriesId, Action<int> progresscallback)
    {

        // set the progress and call the Action(worker.ReportProgress)
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            progresscallback.Invoke(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the events DoWork and RunWorkerComplete. Here is an example counting to 10 and passing the result to a label:

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.Result.ToString(); // getting the result set in DoWork
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        value++;

    e.Result = value; // setting result for RunWorkerCompleted
}
```

The msdn article about this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx